# Emacs keeps guessing wrong coding system on a file I edit both in Linux and Windows

Tags: microsoft-windows, character-encoding

I use Emacs on both Linux and Windows to edit the same files (that I keep in Dropbox, which I hope is irrelevant, but who knows). The files are encoded in utf-8 with Unix line endings. Occasionally, I will notice that when editing them on Windows accented characters display incorrectly which I can correct by telling `M-x recode-region` that the file was really in utf-8 but was interpreted as iso-latin-1.

Why is Emacs incorrectly guessing my file is in iso-latin-1? Why does it only do that on Windows?

Comment: In order to get more details for troubleshooting you could perhaps visit the file literally, or in hexl-mode to find out if the characters in question are encoded as single byte or multi byte characters. Try `M-x hexl-find-file`.

Comment: @KnutForkalsrud This mysteriously stopped happening a while ago. I don't think I could easily reproduce the environment I had when I had this problem. Thanks for the suggestion, though. If I ever experience this problem again, I'll try it.